# Magento sub-category page is not loading

Tags: magento-1.9

I am not **PHP/Magento** developer, I have tried to solve this issue by following a lot of posts, but no luck.

We are managing Magento 1.9.3.4 on ubuntu-16/Ngnix.

One of category(Dropdown menu) is working fine but its remaining pages are not loading and show the blank page, but it is working fine when I refresh the same page. there is no web server or magento error.

**Following URL is working fine**

> https://www.testsite.com.pk/winter-collection.html

**But following is not working**

> https://www.testsite.com.pk/winter-collection.html?p=3 or ?p=2

We have also cleared cache from GUI and CLI. It is happening only with one category, all others are working fine.

Comment: Try this one. https://www.testsite.com.pk/winter-collection.html/?p=3.

Comment: as i mentioned above when i refresh page without /, it opened.
BTW how can i add / in url.

Answer (score 0):

After disabling "Is Anchor" --> no, it is working fine now.

Comment: I did not know this feature of is anchor, I thought it just for layered navigation.

Comment: But it solved my problem. :). i am not magento expert , so no further comment.